# VLC command line audio/video streaming

Tags: c++, visual-c++, streaming, vlc

I am trying to stream audio and video captured from a Webcam (with a mic) to another computer using vlc. I am aware of the way to stream directly using Media option of vlc, but i want to specifically stream it using command line. Is there a way to accomplish this?
The ultimate idea is to call this command line script from a C++ program, so that the streaming can be done on running the C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

Found out the way to stream:

```
vlc -vvv dshow:// :dshow-vdev='USB Video Device' :dshow-adev="Realtek HD Audio Input"  :live-caching=50 :sout=#transcode{vcodec=WMV2,vb=800,acodec=wma2,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:duplicate{dst=udp{dst=localhost:1234},dst=display} :sout-keep
```

Make sure to edit the audio and video device parameters depending on those you are using.